# How to export enum values as individual named exports?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

**Currencies.js**

```
var Currency = {};
Currency["USA"] = "dollar";
Currency["INDIA"] = "rupee";
Currency["CHINA"] = "yuan";

export { Currency };
```

**Test.js**

```
import { Currency } from './currencies';

export { Currency.USA as USA };      // wrong
export { Currency.CHINA as CHINA };  // wrong
export { Currency.INDIA as INDIA };  // wrong
```

**index.js**

```
import { USA } from './Test';

console.log(USA);
```

The issue lies in `Test.js`. The syntax I used for doing named exports is wrong. Can someone correct this? How to individually export object values where the object is imported from somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is too trivial

**#1 method:**

```
const Currency = {
  USA: 'dollar',
  INDIA: 'rupee',
  CHINA: 'yuan'
}
export const { USA, INDIA, CHINA } = Currency;
```

**#2 method(same of #1):**

```
export const { USA, INDIA, CHINA } = {
  USA: 'dollar',
  INDIA: 'rupee',
  CHINA: 'yuan'
};
```

**#3 method:**

```
export const USA = 'dollar';
export const INDIA = 'rupee';
export const CHINA = 'yuan';
```

And you can use it like(all methods):

```
import {USA} form './Currencies'
```